# How to prevent Google Charts from changing x-axis order?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a Google Chart whose x-axis represents the week numbers. As we're crossing a new year, the axis goes `50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, ...`.

I'm properly ordering my data, but Google Charts insists on reordering my x-axis, and I end up with a weird graph:

```js
var chartData = [
  ["Week","Revenue"],
  [40,227],
  [41,317],
  [42,320],
  [43,482],
  [44,418],
  [45,345],
  [46,313],
  [47,316],
  [48,380],
  [49,467],
  [50,349],
  [51,256],
  [52,393],
  [1,276],
  [2,349],
  [3,312]
];

google.load("visualization", "1", {
packages:["corechart"],
callback: function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
  var chart = new google.visualization['LineChart'](div);
  chart.draw(chartDataTable);
}});
```

```html
<div id="chart" style="height: 400px;">test</div>
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

**How can I prevent it from reordering my data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google's *object notation* allows you to provide a value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`)

thus, you can use a value of `1` with a format of `'40'`

e.g. --> `{v: 1, f: '40'}`

in a row --> `[{v: 1, f: '40'},227]`

the following working snippet uses *object notation* to re-format the values for the x-axis,
and re-use those values for the x-axis labels (`hAxis.ticks`)

```js
var chartData = [
  ["Week","Revenue"],
  [40,227],
  [41,317],
  [42,320],
  [43,482],
  [44,418],
  [45,345],
  [46,313],
  [47,316],
  [48,380],
  [49,467],
  [50,349],
  [51,256],
  [52,393],
  [1,276],
  [2,349],
  [3,312]
];

var hAxisTicks = [];
chartData.forEach(function (row, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return;
  }
  row[0] = {
    v: index,
    f: row[0].toString()
  };
  hAxisTicks.push(row[0]);
});

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
    var chart = new google.visualization['LineChart'](div);
    chart.draw(chartDataTable, {
      hAxis: {
        ticks: hAxisTicks
      }
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

**note:**

recommend using `loader.js` to load the the library, instead of `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this only changes the `load` statement, see snippet above...

**EDIT:**

there are more options available for *continuous* axis
which must be sorted, or in reverse sort order (`'number'`, `'date'` values)

but the chart will respect the original sort order for a *discrete* axis (`'string'` values)

see following snippet for `'string'` values

and [discrete vs. continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous) for more...

```js
var chartData = [
  ["Week","Revenue"],
  [40,227],
  [41,317],
  [42,320],
  [43,482],
  [44,418],
  [45,345],
  [46,313],
  [47,316],
  [48,380],
  [49,467],
  [50,349],
  [51,256],
  [52,393],
  [1,276],
  [2,349],
  [3,312]
];

chartData.forEach(function (row, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return;
  }
  row[0] = row[0].toString();
});

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
    var chart = new google.visualization['LineChart'](div);
    chart.draw(chartDataTable);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks! I'm surprised, though, that Google Charts doesn't have a simple setting to respect the order given to `arrayToDataTable()` (and even more that this isn't the default!)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I like the second solution, which is simpler and perfectly suited to my needs!